# swap equivalent events in the conditional probability in general

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Following the idea from
[Can we swap equivalent events in the conditional part?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626165/can-we-swap-equivalent-events-in-the-conditional-part/4626399?noredirect=1#comment9759206_4626399)

I'm wondering if $E[f(Y)|I_{Z=X},X]$ and $E[f(Y)|Z,X]$ match almost surely over $w\in \{Z=X\}$, for any random elements $X,Y,Z$ and real-valued function f.

If this does not hold in general, under what condition does it hold? (e.g. does regular conditional probability or disintegration help?)

---

This is motivated by the following "intuitive" but unjustified operation:

$P(T(Y)\leq y|Z=X, X=x) = P(T(Y)\leq y|Z=x, X=x)$

(I think in elementary probability courses people tend to do this quite often, but after we introduce the measure-theoretic definition, I'm not sure how to properly describe and justify this using the language from measure theory.)

Comment: Did you mean $E[f(Y)|I_{Z=X},Z]$ for the second expectation? As written, the first one will generally be conditioning on more information.

Comment: @Adam Ah sorry, I now edited my question. The source of my question roots from the motivation below and I was trying to make that "operation" generic.